# Error :- Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

```
SELECT TOP 20
total_worker_time/execution_count AS Avg_CPU_Time
,Execution_count
,total_elapsed_time/execution_count as AVG_Run_Time
,total_elapsed_time
,(SELECT
SUBSTRING(text,statement_start_offset/2+1,statement_end_offset
) FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
) AS Query_Text
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats
ORDER BY Avg_CPU_Time DESC
```

Comment: Please add some data to your question which demonstrates the problem.  We can't really answer this just by seeing the query.

Comment: sir actually i am trying to find Problematic Queries in my database ,i cant share my database because of some professional commitments

Comment: If you can't add sample data which demonstrates the problem, I'll bet you won't get an answer which would be usable.

Comment: `SUBSTRING(text,statement_start_offset/2+1,statement_end_offset)`  - verify if the statement_end_offset variable has the right value
length. Read the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)